# How to handle fixed header with scroll-able body

Tags: html, css, markup

I've created a 3 column layout with a fixed header and a scroll-able body nested between two columns. the issue is that the body shifts over when a scrollbar is not present causing it to become un-aligned with the header.

Is there a more elegant way to create this layout. Or any other solution for the scroll jumping?

the only restrictions I have are
.the scrollbar should appear at the very right hand of the screen
.the left and right hand columns should not scroll with the body
.scrollbar should not be present when not scroll-able
.should work in IE11

I've tried to implement the solution on this blog, but no success in implementing it to my layout.
https://css-tricks.com/elegant-fix-jumping-scrollbar-issue/

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EqjNRJ

```html
<section id="container">
  <div id="col1">col1</div>
  <div id="col2">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="bode">Body</div>
  </div>
  <div id="col3">col3</div>  
</section>
```

```css
#header{
  background-color:teal;
  height:70px;
  position:fixed;
  width:calc(100% - 585px);
  margin-right:100px;
}

#bode{
  margin-top:70px;
  background-color:aqua;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#col1{
  border: 5px solid red;
  width:250px;
}

#col2{
  flex: 1;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding-right:278px;
  padding-left:20px
}

#col3{
  position: fixed;
  margin-right:23px;
  right:0;    
  bottom:0;
  top:0;  
  width:250px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

Comment: use position:sticky instead fixed https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qebqjp

Comment: @G-Cyr sadly position:sticky is not supported in IE

Comment: Is it ok to use jq?